# Android - Is it possible to use a parent view's content description?

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

For accessibility, I have a few with multiple view inside and I want them to all have the same content description. Is it possible to just set it for the parent view and have the child views use it instead of manually setting it for each view?

I tried making the child view clickable=false, but that did not solve the problem

Comment: Are those views important for accessibility? If not, set `importantForAccessibility` to `no` on them.

Comment: Thanks @siger . I added it to the view and now it just falls through to the parent view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those views aren't important for accessibility, set the `importantForAccessibility` property to `no` on them.